# React window resize doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code only runs when i actively resize the window, and not when I load the page say on a smartphone for example.

```
handleResize() {
        if(window.innerWidth <= 650 && this.state.skipLenght !== 2){
            this.setState({portLength: 2})
        } 
        else if (window.innerWidth <= 950 && window.innerWidth >= 650 && this.state.portLength !== 4){
            this.setState({portLength: 4})
        }else if (window.innerWidth <= 1250 && window.innerWidth >= 950 && this.state.portLength !== 6){
            this.setState({portLength: 6})
        } else if (window.innerWidth >= 1250 && this.state.portLength !== 8){
            this.setState({portLength: 8})
        }
    }

 componentDidMount() {
     window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
 }
    
 componentWillUnmount() {
     window.removeEventListener("resize", this.handleResize);
 }
```

Comment: Call the event as well `window.addEventListener("resize", this.handleResize); this.handleResize();`?